# Modify javascript to let show previous years

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript code, i guess this should be where the code has to be changed.

```
 if (this.options.showYear) {
            str += '<select tabindex="'+this.tabIndex+'" class="' + this.options.yearClass + '">';
            if (this.options.yearOrder == 'desc'){
                for (var y = this.options.yearStart; y > (this.options.yearStart - this.options.yearRange - 1); y--){
                    str += this.addOption(y,y,parseInt(this.calendarYear));
                }
            } else {
                for (var y = this.options.yearStart; y < (this.options.yearStart + this.options.yearRange + 1); y++){
                    str += this.addOption(y,y,parseInt(this.calendarYear));
                }
            }
```

The calendar is currently showing only 2013 and above, i need at least 2012..
Please help me with this!
Thanks

```
 dayChars: 1,
        monthNames: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
        dayNames: ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'],
        daysInMonth: [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31], // Leap year is added later
        format: 'yyyy/mm/dd',                                          // How the output looks after selection
        yearStart: (new Date().getFullYear()),                     // Default starting year for dropdown options is 5 years ago
        yearRange: 10,                                                 // Show a 10 year span
        yearOrder: 'asc',                                              // Counting up in years
        startDay: 7
```

Comment: your context Object has a propertie `options` which again has a `yearStart` propertie, change it to your needs

Comment: A little more context please. Where is `options` defined?

Comment: Way too little information. It is a guessing game here. Also, you do not show any effort or insight.

Comment: i updated my question please take a look..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change in your options

```
yearStart: (new Date().getFullYear()),
```

to

```
yearStart: (new Date().getFullYear() - 1), // or any number of years you want to go back
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (this.options.showYear) {
    str += '<select tabindex="'+this.tabIndex+'" class="' + this.options.yearClass + '">';

    this.options.yearStart -= 1;
```

or change options.yearStart to 2012 instead of 2013 (current year)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
if(this.options.yearStart >= 2013) {
    this.options.yearStart = 2012;
}
```

Or

```
dayChars: 1,
monthNames: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
dayNames: ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'],
daysInMonth: [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31], // Leap year is added later
format: 'yyyy/mm/dd',                                          // How the output looks after selection
yearStart: ((new Date().getFullYear()) < 2013 ? (new Date().getFullYear()) : 2012),  // Default starting year for dropdown options is 5 years ago
yearRange: 10,                                                 // Show a 10 year span
yearOrder: 'asc',                                              // Counting up in years
startDay: 7
```

Answer (score 0):

```
yearStart: ((new Date().getFullYear()) - 1),
```